# How to fit URL image into the screen on android?

Tags: android, image

i am getting image from url but its not fitting with the screen as its showing on browser...kindly help..i tried everything..this the url 
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg"
here is the image[image]

if we run the url on browser, we can see tht on my device its slightly upside..i want it to look perfect on my device

here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/main1" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"

                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                android:src="@drawable/pl2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/l1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be set as background image of your screen and the other two images to be placed on top of it?

Comment: no this is 1st image other below image are 2nd and 3rd

Comment: no background image its main screen image

Comment: its a 70:30 ratio 1st image should capture 70 percent of the screen and others 30 %

Comment: For the ratios you have correctly used the weights and to show the image in the correct adjustment of the image in the ImageView you can set adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: its still same with no difference

Comment: Please set another image or any default image and check it, is it working or not?

Comment: i am using ----Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("https://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png").into(im1);

Comment: i dont know whr r problm is

Comment: wotever image i take in url it cuts slightly upside

Comment: This is your whole scree xml file because i used this code and it's work fine?

Comment: yes...i have three image on screen...1 is above and 2 is below 70:30  ratio

Comment: i tried with other images from url but its still the same...slightly cut from above

Comment: You put one image in your drawable folder and set that image in image view and check that is it working or not?

Comment: that is also cutting and doent look perfectly fit

Comment: its not looking perfect ans slightly cutted from top if i use drawble image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132995/discussion-between-shailesh-and-z-al).

Comment: hi, i tried ur example , but still my image is going upward..can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Imageview ,

```
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: wotever image i take in url it cuts slightly upside

Comment: clean your project and try again

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library known as glide for this purpose

Comment: how to use it into code...as i have use picasso for url image

Comment: i m new to android ..so dont knw much abt it...if u tell me through coding thn it wud b grt

Comment: wotever image i take in url it cuts slightly upside

Answer (score 0):

See if it works.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/main1"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/pl2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/l1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no just showing single image ..but the top is still cutted

Comment: I edited the answer right after posting. Can you try again?

Comment: wotever image i take in url it cuts slightly upside