# Imageview is not filling its parent

Tags: android

1. Image with size (width: 1080px height: 1920px)
2. Phone is xxhdpi which has a resolution of (width: 1080px height: 1920px)

In output you can see there is a white gap in start and end of the imageView.

I don't want to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` because it stretches the image. I know the gaps is because of the status bar and navigation bar the imageview tries to maintain its ratio.

Is it possible to fill the imageview without doing anything to the image source.Thanks in advance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/plain" />
```

Output:
[image: sample output]

Comment: Your screen is same size with picture but it have to show status bar and virtual navigation.

Comment: `scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: add `scaleType="fitXY"` to your imageview in xml

Comment: @TruongHieu I know. but is there any work around. How can i make it constant in all the phone with virtual navigation and without virtual navigation bar?

Comment: Make it becomes fullscreen activity

Comment: I can't do that. But i can resize the image can u tell me what image size can i use so that it will fit properly.

Comment: You can't do what you seem to want.  You have an image that's NxM.  You have a phone screen that's Nx(M-H).  That means when you display it, you either have to stretch it to fit, or you have bands on the sides.  You can change the color of those bands, but that's about all.  Its a simple matter of math.  For something this small of a difference I'd stretch to fit, the artificating should be minimal

Comment: Use android:scaleType="centerCrop" in your imageView

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611512/how-to-fit-url-image-into-the-screen-on-android/41611852#41611852

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: You can simply use "cropXYZ" instead of "XYZ" for your scaleType. This will cause that the image is adapted to the available space without loosing the image aspect ratio

Comment: Is putting activity in fullscreen mode acceptable solution?

Comment: @RobinVinzenz Can u explain bit more. there is nothing called cropXYZ in scaleType

Comment: @AlexandarG No, that is not my requirement.

Comment: There is no built-in scale type that allows the ImageView to automatically upscale the image and keep its aspect ratio intact i guess,you need a work around.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202000/imageview-one-dimension-to-fit-free-space-and-second-evaluate-to-keep-aspect-rat

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use fitXY,or modify the img,maybe you can use `android:background="@drawable/img"` replace `android:src=@drawable/img`,Did you like this?

Comment: Yes I did like it? But i have a question  ? is fitXY an alternative for android:backgroud or android:src mm which language ?

Comment: http://blog.csdn.net/dalleny/article/details/14048375  ,I think it's a good answer

Comment: you link only shows 您要找的资源已被删除、已更名或暂时不可用。 it should be this i guess http://blog.csdn.net/dalleny/article/details/14048375 but that doesnt load eaither

Comment: It's Ok now,try again.

Comment: did you use scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: if use centerCrop,width will fill screen,but height will crop header and booter,to fix the screen,(h > w).